# How to align equations with the inequality sign separated from the right-hand-side math material?

Tags: equations, align

I do

```
\newcommand{\va}[1]{\left | #1 \right |}

[...]

\begin{align*}
  & \va{\crochets{\frac{-\cos(nt)}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{e^t-1}}_{\varepsilon}^A} \\
 \leq  &\frac{1}{n} \cdot \left (
 \frac{\va{\cos(A)}}{e^A -1}
+ \frac{\va{\cos(\varepsilon)}}{e^\varepsilon -1} 
\right )\\
\leq & \frac{1}{n} \cdot \left (
 \frac{1}{e^A -1}
+ \frac{1}{e^\varepsilon -1} 
\right )\\
\leq & \frac{1}{n} \cdot \left (
 \frac{2}{e^\varepsilon -1} 
\right ).
\end{align*}
```

and I get

[image]

How could I improve the layout of the equations? I would like the `\leq` sign to be a little bit more separated from the equations.

Comment: There are a lot of control sequences (e.g. `\va`) which are provided by specific packages. It would really help if you included a preamble so that we don't have to work out where they come from ourselves :) `\crochets` is completely new to me. I assume `\va` is from the `physics` package? Or have you defined these commands yourself?

Comment: why not add spaces (\ ) ?

Comment: You might want to have a look at `\MoveEqLeft` from the `mathtools ` package, that is my goto tool for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to add `\quad` and to change the position of `&` after the `\leq`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   & \abs*{\left[\frac{-\cos(nt)}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{e^{t} -
        1}\right]_{\varepsilon}^A} 
  \\[2mm]
   \leq \quad &\frac{1}{n} \cdot
  \left(\frac{\abs{\cos(A)}}{e^{A} - 1} +
    \frac{\abs{\cos(\varepsilon)}}{e^\varepsilon-1}\right)
  \\
   \leq \quad&\frac{1}{n} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{e^{A} -1 } +
    \frac{1}{e^{\varepsilon} - 1}\right)
  \\
   \leq \quad&\frac{1}{n} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{e^{\varepsilon} - 1}\right).
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `\le{}&` if you really want this; `\quad` is too much.

Answer (score 7):

This is just an addition to AU101s answer using mathtools and `\MoveEqleft`. The idea is to use a recommendation from a pamphlet from the AMS that instructs users to align on the left and indent subsequent lines by 2em. This does the opposite, aligns at the relation and pulls back the first line by 2em.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \MoveEqLeft \abs*{\left[\frac{-\cos(nt)}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{e^{t} -
        1}\right]_{\varepsilon}^A} 
  \\
  & \leq \frac{1}{n} \cdot
  \left(\frac{\abs{\cos(A)}}{e^{A} - 1} +
    \frac{\abs{\cos(\varepsilon)}}{e^\varepsilon-1}\right)
  \\
  & \leq \frac{1}{n} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{e^{A} -1 } +
    \frac{1}{e^{\varepsilon} - 1}\right)
  \\
  & \leq \frac{1}{n} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{e^{\varepsilon} - 1}\right).
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend (sorry I used naive commands instead of `\va`, `\crochets`, etc. because I'm more familiar with them):

```
\begin{align*}
  \left|\left[\frac{-\cos(nt)}{n} \cdot
  \frac{1}{e^{t} - 1}\right]_{\varepsilon}^A\right|
  & \leq \frac{1}{n} \cdot \left(\frac{|\cos(A)|}{e^{A} - 1} +
    \frac{|\cos(\varepsilon)|}{e^\varepsilon-1}\right) \\
  & \leq \frac{1}{n} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{e^{A} -1 } +
    \frac{1}{e^{\varepsilon} - 1}\right) \\
  & \leq \frac{1}{n} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{e^{\varepsilon} -
    1}\right).
\end{align*}
```

[image]

This aligns all of the `\leq`s vertically and is generally the expected behaviour. You are aligning what comes after the `\leq`s, which destroys the ability to see `\leq` as a binary operator.

More generally, unless you come from a very different mathematical culture to mine, you should never have the Left Hand Side of an equation/inequality on its own line and then a line break. You have a = b (or < or > or whatever) and then your new line. This, certainly, is the type of layout the `align` environment was designed for.

Comment: Yes you are right but I don't have enough horizontal space...

Answer (score 1):

You should interchange the order of `&` and `\leq`. If horizontal space is at a premium, I would also get rid of the `\cdot` directives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\DeclarePairedDelimiter" macro
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& \abs*{\left[\frac{-\cos(nt)}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{e^t-1}\right]_{\varepsilon}^A} \\
 &\leq  \frac{1}{n} \left (
 \frac{\abs{\cos(A)}}{e^A -1}
+ \frac{\abs{\cos(\varepsilon)}}{e^\varepsilon -1} 
\right )\\
&\leq   \frac{1}{n} \left (
 \frac{1}{e^A -1}
+ \frac{1}{e^\varepsilon -1} 
\right )\\
&\leq   \frac{1}{n} \left (
 \frac{2}{e^\varepsilon -1} 
\right ).
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The code above deliberately produces a very compact look, as I gather from your comment on @Au101's answer that horizontal space is quite limited. If you have a bit of horizontal space to spare, you could take up the comment made by @egreg (see below) and insert `\quad` between `&` and `\leq` on lines 2, 3, and 4, to provide at least a hint of horizontal offset.

Comment: Consider adding a quad at the left of the lines after the first.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `\hspace{-...}` before `\leq` signs and `\hspace{...}` after `\leq` signs. But it is probably too simple to fulfil your requirements. :)

Comment: Well, I think it is better to use `&``, because with that you get the marked character with `&` to be one over the other.  Or can you please show a complete code how your suggestion can work?